# How do you make an image opened in colorbox scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I would like my images that I open in colorbox to be displayed fullsize with no resizing applied to them and then apply scrollbars to allow for viewing the larger images.  Some of my images are quite tall and things get pixelated when resized down.

Currently colorbox just resizes my images down to the size of the available height/width.  Is there a way to make all images display fullsize with overflow scrollable in colorbox?

I am linking directly to an image:

```
<a href="/myimage.png" title="My Image" class="colorbox imagefield imagefield-imagelink imagefield-field_portfolio_screenshot initColorbox-processed cboxElement" rel="gallery-12">
  <img src="/thumb/myimage.png" alt="image" title="My Image" class="imagecache imagecache-portfolio_screenshot_thumb" height="50" width="50">
</a>
```

Comment: BTW, I have found the option to do maxHeight: false but this only sets it so the browser scrollbar will scroll the colorbox.  I want the colorbox itself to have a scrollbar and the colorbox to be set to a maxheight of say 80%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to tack on query strings onto my url, so I came up with this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var height = ((window.innerHeight || $window.height()) - 100);
  var width;
  $(".iframed-image").each(function() {
    $("<img/>").attr("src", $(this).attr('href')).load(function() {
      width = this.width;
    });
    $(this).colorbox({
        html: '<div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:' + height + 'px;width:' + width + 'px;"><img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" /></div>'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://yourjavascript.com/15102656623/jquery-colorbox-min-1-6-4.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <h2>Image in iframe</h2>
    <p><a href="http://lorempixel.com/640/1044/" title="Random 640x1044 image" class="iframed-image">Random 640x1044 Image in iframe</a></p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by opening the image in frame using colorbox

Comment: but how would one go about putting it into the frame if it is a direct link to an image.  Is there some sort of jquery to alter the linked image to open in such manner?

Comment: just put an image in separate file and open this file with colorbox frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `?foo=.php` to URL and set width and/or height less than image's value.

http://example.com/example.jpg
http://example.com/example.jpg?foo=.php

```
$('a.gallery').colorbox({height:'50%'});
```