# I Want to enable vertical scroll on colorbox to show images with large height

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, resize, colorbox

I have very "long" images that I want to display in a colorbox with a width of 1000px but I want to be able to scroll inside the colorbox. [Like this but with a fixed height and a vertical scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5bWz.jpg) (The scrollbars you see on the right side are part of the image, not actual scrollbars)

This is what happens when I set a fixed height of 500px to try and force scrollbars: [The image is resized to fit in the colorbox as a whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swc1G.jpg)

I'd greatly appreciate any help as I've searched all over the internet but everyone just seems to want to DISABLE scrolling. I want the opposite. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using a `height: [xxx]px` or `max-height: [xxx]px` with an `overflow: auto` on the container

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12208519/882098

Comment: I think the link Daniel posted should get you what you're looking for. It's doing the same thing I suggested, but specifically with colorbox

Comment: Did you try it how the answer Daniel linked suggested?

Comment: I'm trying to fit it into my code. The way I see it I just have to replace ".iframed-image" with "#myID" and delete my existing colorbox function, right?

Comment: It doesn't call colorbox if I try it like this. It must be something with this code snippet

 `$("<img/>").attr("src", $(this).attr('href')).load(function() {
            width = this.width;`

If I remove it and just set the width to say 1000, colorbox is opened but the image's WIDTH isn't fitted to the CB container.

Comment: Try removing the `width = this.width` and place the `style="width: 1000px"` on the `<img>` in the html string in the `.colorbox()` function where you are specifying the html. Also try removing the `.. + height + ..` and `..+ width + ..` from the html string as well, just hard code those for now to get it working

Comment: @Dario Much closer. Does it actually scroll?

Comment: @mhodges I got it working: http://i.imgur.com/cRhtWZ1.jpg 
This is what my code looks like now: 

`var height = ((window.innerHeight || $window.height()) - 100);
    var width = 1000;
    $("#test").each(function() {
        $(this).colorbox({
            height: "600px",
            html: '<div style="overflow-y:scroll;"><img  style="width:1000px;" src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" /></div>'            
        });
     });`
Thank you for your extensive help! And thank you @Daniel Hall for the initial push in the right direction!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you got it working. You should post an answer with all of your relevant code and an explanation of how you got it to work so I can upvote it and so future viewers don't have to dig through the comments to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works:
After following @Daniel Hall's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208519/882098) I replaced my colorbox function with that code and made some changes:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cb-lp").each(function() {
           $(this).colorbox({
               height: "600px",
               html: '<div style="overflow-y:scroll;"><img style="width:1000px;" 
                       src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" /></div>' 
            });
     }); 
});`

HTML Code: 
`<a href="images/projects/landing/LandingPage2.jpg" class="cb-lp">Landing Page #1</a>`

This is what the working result looks like for me: [Scrollable Colorbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LSKP.jpg)

There is still a horizontal scroll at the very bottom of the image but in my case it is even benefivial. Removing this might require some more tweaks. Thanks again for helping me, @Daniel Hall and @mhodges